# Insert data from a Subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I'm trying to insert values obtained through a subquery into a specific column already created. I have the following:

```
    INSERT INTO insights_database(changes)
    SELECT 
       Message
    FROM 
       insights_database
    WHERE Message (SELECT *, SUBSTR(Message,LOCATE('campaign_id =',Message)) AS changes
        FROM database.insights_database
        WHERE Message LIKE '%campaign_id =%');
```

This throws an error in MySQL and I can't figure out how to insert the value resulting from that subquery into the column.

Thanks!!

Comment: IN Clause missing. It should be like WHERE Message IN (your subquery). Also,  subquery should select only message instead of *

Comment: Also - INSERT inserts new row, not a value to the column in existing row.